# Complex sentence without a dependent maker word?

Tags: clauses, syntax

To practice compound-complex sentences I write the following sentence:

Two young people meet, finding that they are clicking with each other, and then they get married.

I wonder if the first two clauses form a complex sentence? The first clause is an independent sentence and the second cannot stand alone as a sentence and is dependent on the first one, but it seems that a dependent maker word is not necessary here. I know dependent maker words are [words](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/independent_and_dependent_clauses/index.html) like after, although, as, as if, because, before, even if, even though, if, in order to, since, though, unless, until, whatever, when, whenever, whether, and while.

Or is my sentence a legal compound-complex sentence?

Comment: It doesn't make sense semantically. The "finding...clicking" has to happen after they meet. You could have a compound sentence "Two people meet, find that they click with each other, and get married.

Comment: It works if they're castanet-players who meet for the first time while playing at a gig. But you don't need the last "they".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I thought this would be a compound-complex sentence: Two young people meet, and then get married because they click with each other.

Comment: @LernerZhang  Yes, that is compound-complex.